# Alternative to the default friend picker?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there an alternative version of the FB friend picker? I have noticed on a number of FB games that they use an interface that looks like the one I have attached to this post. Is this a standard FB picker or have FB developers just decided on a style and are all borrowing from each other? Thanks. [image: friend picker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog you post is a custom solution that a lot of apps include in their apps,
i don't know what and where to find this but you can build your own by calling all the friends via Graph API,

or you can use something like this:
http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbklistselection-like-facebook-friends-selector.html
http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html

Answer (score 0):

I image that you are connected to the app and that the app has permission to read your friendlist to manually display such a list.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an old, deprecated picker that sends the old-style requests - these are super-deprecated and will be removed soon

The only currently supported method for doing this is the [Requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) which looks like this:
 [image]

Comment: Actually, there is another way of doing it with a bit of extra work. See my answer for information.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom friend selector in a few steps.

1. Call the API and get a list of the user's friends
2. Display the list to the user and let them select the friends they want to invite (you can use checkboxes or another method for doing this).
3. Use the single / multiple request JavaScript function described here to send the requests: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#direct_request

This will let you display the friends list as you want, but still send the requests correctly using the API.